# How to take an input that is equal to 10 and perform a function that says awesome to the screen

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to create a function that takes a users input and if it equals 10 then perform a function that will eventually print fizzbuzz to the screen from 0-10 but for now I'm just trying to get it to say "awesome" if the input == 10. Here is the code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Fizzbuzz Input Field</title>
        <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="number" id="userInput"></input>
            <button onclick="fizzBuzz()">Go</button>
        </form>
    </body>

    </html>

    window.onload = function() {
        alert("Page is loaded");
    };

    var fizzBuzz = function() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
        fizzBuzz.onclick = function() {
        if(userInput.value == 10) { 
            document.write("awesome");
        };
        };
    }
```

Comment: you may need to put the javascript part inside a script tag. or is that just a typing convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the element from the input, in this case, "userInput". grab your button by querying it, or putting an id on it etc... Don't bother with putting a function on the HTML, avoid bad practice. Add an event listener to the button, check to see if it equals 10 and append your text, preferably somewhere suitable.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("userInput");
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]
button.addEventListener('click', function(a) {
  if (input.value === '10') {
    button.after("awesome");
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="userInput">
<button>Go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `eval` before using it, you should search the web for why `eval` is *evil*.

Comment: I think OP quite literally means 'equals 10' and not 'evaluates to 10'.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a property 'onclick' of function 'fizzBuzz',
you should use the input event.

```
var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput');
userInput.oninput = function() {

    if( this.value == 10 ) alert('awesome');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // First we get the numeric value written to the input (or NaN if it's not a number)
    var inputValue = parseInt(document.getElementById('userInput').value, 10);
    // Define the element to which write the text (you usually want a DIV for this)
    var outputElement = document.getElementById('outputDiv');

    if ( ! isNaN(inputValue) ) {
        outputElement.innerHTML = "awesome!";
    }
    else {
        // The value is not a number, so just clean the result
        outputElement.innerHTML = "";
    }
});
```

Of course, for this to work, you should have at least:

```
<input type="number" id="userInput" />
<button id="myButton">Go</button>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any idea how you want the awesome to be displayed. Made it an alert. Have fun.

```js
<script>
function fizzBuzz() {
var fizzBuzz = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
if(fizzBuzz != 10){
 alert('Number is not equal to ten!');
 }else {
     alert('awesome');
    }
    
}
</script>
```